# Google one time code flow oauth login is not working in windows phone IE

Tags: oauth, google-plus, google-oauth, google-signin, google-oauth-java-client

Im using google one time code flow oauth login for my site, which described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow),
Now my problem is the link is working fine and google is asking my username and password then it is just hagging over there no response and not redirecting to my site only in windows phone IE.

My guess is that it is opening in the same window so it will not able to find the callback function in my site,
I dont know how to fix this now. Anyone please help me to fix this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify a few things: What version of windows phone are you using (so we can test)? Are you seeing any errors on the device? Are you using the Google+ sign-in button? If so, is JavaScript disabled on the phone browser?

Comment: Im using lumia 920, javascript is not disabled because all other places are working fine. I'm using google+ sign-in button only.

Comment: I don't have a Windows Phone around, but I'll see if I can reproduce the issue in the VS device simulator. Please file a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list